# Do VAOs also automatically bind indices arrays?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, vbo, vao

I've seen many programs doing this in the initialization phase (pseudocode):

```
glGenVertexArrays(vao)
glBindVertexArray(vao)

glGenBuffers(vbo)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
glBufferData(into the vbo)

glVertexAttribPointer(instruct the vao on vbo's memory organization)

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // Unbind VBO
glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO

glGenBuffers(vbo for indices)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo for indices)
glBufferData(populate indices vbo)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // Unbind vbo for indices
```

is this the proper way  of doing it? Does the VAO also store a reference to the indices vbo so that I could unbind the vao after the vbo for indices is also initialized (and avoid binding the vbo for indices at all in the drawing phase)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a VAO does store the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding.

But note, that it always stores the last state before unbinding the VAO. So if you call `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` before unbinding the VOA, the binding is removed. In your case, you also unbound the VAO before binding the index buffer, thus no binding is stored here.

The correct code code look like this:

```
lGenVertexArrays(vao)
glBindVertexArray(vao)

glGenBuffers(vbo)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
glBufferData(into the vbo)

glVertexAttribPointer(instruct the vao on vbo's memory organization)

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // Unbind VBO

glGenBuffers(vbo for indices)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo for indices)
glBufferData(populate indices vbo)

glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // Unbind vbo for indices
```

Comment: oh, interesting. And the same doesn't hold for the non-indices VBOs, right? I see that you're unbinding the VBO **before** unbinding the VAO.

Comment: That's because `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` bindings are (basically) established by the `glVertexAttribPointer` call.

Comment: thank you. That wasn't so easy to understand from the khronos documentation.